# Twitchy Sprite Movement (Java)

Tags: java, vector, 2d, sprite

I'm having an issue with sprite movement, and I'm not sure how to deal with it.

When I set a destination for my player sprite (by clicking the screen), it sets the player moving in that direction. Unfortunately, the player sort of... oscillates. He sort of shivers along the path.

I've set up a test project using just graphics primitives (graphics.fillRect(x,y,w,h)), and its really easy to see. Here's a sort of example without using video/gifs:

[image: Wut]

My code looks like this

```
public void tick() {

    if (InputHandler.leftClick.heldDown) {
        dest.setLocation(InputHandler.leftClick.xPos, InputHandler.leftClick.yPos);
    }

    direction.setLocation(dest.getX() - position.x, dest.getY() - position.y);
    direction.normalize();
    position.add(direction.multiply(velocity));
}
```

This is a really really basic movement system because I'm having the same issues elsewhere and I wanted to work on them in a more controlled environment.

The weirdest part about this is that when the player arrives, he still just sits on one point, shivering madly.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

There's a little discrepancy? between what you said, "clicking on the screen" and `heldDown`. Have you read about mouse event handlers? But I see that you want to go on a tick by tick basis. It would be more clear to have a boolean flag that alerts you if the path was changed. Then this segment would look like

```
if (leftclicked) {
    dest.setLocation(InputHandler.leftClick.xPos, InputHandler.leftClick.yPos);
    leftclicked = false;
}
...
```

Strictly, in physics, velocity is a vector. It has both direction and magnitude. If you intend this as simply a speed at which the thing can move, with instant turning, the next three lines should be fine, although the readability seems improvable. (You have to be sure of what all the helper methods are doing. I'd probably prefer to do whatever calculations needed right here in one place.)

However I suspect you do have `velocity` as something like vector. There is some notion of momentum in here. I think the `multiply()` method is implemented strangely. If it adds/combines the angle of `velocity` with the angle of `direction` behavior like this results. Having an aspect of momentum is cool but if desired you should really think how to do it.

Another explanation is that the code you've shown works as intended, inching the thing along the direction of the black line, but some other part of your code is messing with `position`. We weren't given a picture of what happens on arrival...

One more thing about readability. It's very important..."really really basic" things can be buggy swamps without simple organizing steps. I have to rewrite implementations several times because I get overeager and miss designs. It looks like you are doing well at my bane, the "one method/object does one thing (well)" principle but getting into trouble with...naming, of all things. Example: `direction.setLocation()` Now, directions do not have locations. Repeat: directions do not have locations. Also, directions don't need to be normalized - they don't have lengths.

Instead:

```
direction = new Direction(dx, dy);
position.add(direction.multiply(MOVEMENT_SPEED));//assuming constant speed
```

where

```
//sensible encapsulation of "direction"
class Direction {
    double angle;//angle in degrees

    //constructs a direction from cartesian coordinates
    Direction(int x, int y){
        angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan((double)y/x));
    }

    //create a vector of specified length in this direction
    java.awt.Point multiply(double amt){
        return new java.awt.Point(amt*Math.cos(angle), amt*Math.sin(angle))
    }
    ...
}
```

Hmm long answer...please try for crystal clear code and questions in future! :)